# Prediction interval for linear regression on seasonal data in R

Tags: r, regression

I am using the following code to perform a generalized linear regression which produces a satisfying prediction for this highly seasonal time series. i am just not very satisfied with the prediction interval.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <-  data.frame(
  Year = c(2010:2022),
  Jan = c(9.125190, 11.246194, 10.005710, 11.860997, 8.479577, 12.217544, 10.936131, 14.231219, 12.528664, 9.708485, 9.546312, 6.404898, 7.722706),
  Feb = c(8.244732, 8.542226, 10.596979, 10.517831, 6.879523, 10.347170, 8.959616, 10.629507, 12.617676, 9.817436, 9.214408, 5.813070, 6.241632),
  Mar = c(9.238563, 9.235491, 11.883677, 9.317300, 8.394458, 11.385139, 10.020984, 9.769718, 11.902048, 9.636609, 9.235649, 5.518358, 6.808591),
  Apr = c(7.544589, 7.849008, 9.425192, 8.402769, 8.286355, 7.175516, 7.569861, 8.181405, 9.260685, 8.746594, 7.098291, 5.712981, 8.022114),
  May = c(7.507712, 7.880196, 7.474539, 7.711562, 7.122297, 6.904684, 7.617312, 8.436277, 7.300628, 7.469907, 5.351538, 5.522463, 8.118739),
  Jun = c(7.155556, 7.267345, 8.082705, 6.552630, 6.105434, 7.130457, 6.481846, 7.367343, 6.203369, 7.088462, 4.881926, 4.714001, 6.755348),
  Jul = c(7.553177, 7.282860, 7.608614, 6.677641, 7.297347, 6.809597, 7.401806, 7.442650, 6.141153, 6.884004, 4.901695, 5.349021, 6.622962),
  Aug = c(7.386405, 6.634843, 6.831688, 6.620460, 6.730343, 6.515561, 6.629869, 6.228851, 6.351408, 6.473058, 5.624823, 6.151726, 7.066329),
  Sep = c(6.989513, 7.744634, 6.679978, 6.488205, 6.691177, 6.463346, 6.524750, 6.080630, 5.815100, 6.493823, 5.865662, 6.225765, 6.345742),
  Oct = c(8.583059, 7.933706, 7.188722, 7.922748, 7.014266, 7.942714, 7.213666, 7.086810, 6.034656, 7.306795, 5.763610, 7.475580, 6.685429),
  Nov = c(7.414235, 7.370885, 7.389827, 6.939339, 6.688794, 6.866514, 7.564838, 7.305519, 6.369718, 6.137456, 5.682223, 7.664962, 6.868851),
  Dec = c(9.846751, 9.502180, 9.791360, 8.241256, 8.753308, 8.061643, 11.675325, 10.032838, 7.465993, 8.229741, 5.661139, 8.448881, 10.819879)
)|>
  pivot_longer(names_to = "Month", values_to = "Value", -Year) |>
  mutate(Month = factor(Month, levels = month.abb))
  
m <- glm(Value ~ Year + Month,
             # family =, # I don't really feel confident assuming normality here
                         # but ciTools doesn't support quasipoisson
             data = df |> filter(Year<2020))

library(ciTools)

df <- add_pi(df, m, names = c("lower_pi", "upper_pi"), yhatName = "Predicted")
df <- add_ci(df, m, names = c("lower_ci", "upper_ci"), yhatName = "Predicted")

df |> 
  mutate(time = 2010 +(row_number()-0.5)/12) |>
  ggplot(aes(x = time)) + 
  labs(x = "", y = "", linetype = "", fill = "", color = "") +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower_pi, ymax = upper_pi, fill = "95% pi"), alpha = 1) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower_ci, ymax = upper_ci, fill = "95% ci"), alpha = 1) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Predicted, linetype = "Predicted")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Value, linetype = "Observed")) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 2020, color = "End of training period")) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, NA)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(2010, 2022, 1), minor_breaks = NULL) +
  theme(legend.position = "top")
```

[image: A graph of observed and predicted data]

I would expect it to look a lot more like this boxplot diagram showing much smaller variance in summer time.

```r
df |>
  filter(Year<2020) |>
  ggplot(aes(x = Month, y = Value)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gaussian models assume constant residual variance.  Since the residual variance is part of the prediction interval, you're adding the same constant term across all months.

To fix this, you should use a family in which the variance is a function of the mean, or vary the residual variance term as a function of the predictors.  I'll demonstrate how to model the residual variance with a Bayesian model (though I think it is possible to do this with GEEs, I don't know how).

```
library(tidyverse)
library(brms)
library(tidybayes)
d <-  data.frame(
  Year = c(2010:2022),
  Jan = c(9.125190, 11.246194, 10.005710, 11.860997, 8.479577, 12.217544, 10.936131, 14.231219, 12.528664, 9.708485, 9.546312, 6.404898, 7.722706),
  Feb = c(8.244732, 8.542226, 10.596979, 10.517831, 6.879523, 10.347170, 8.959616, 10.629507, 12.617676, 9.817436, 9.214408, 5.813070, 6.241632),
  Mar = c(9.238563, 9.235491, 11.883677, 9.317300, 8.394458, 11.385139, 10.020984, 9.769718, 11.902048, 9.636609, 9.235649, 5.518358, 6.808591),
  Apr = c(7.544589, 7.849008, 9.425192, 8.402769, 8.286355, 7.175516, 7.569861, 8.181405, 9.260685, 8.746594, 7.098291, 5.712981, 8.022114),
  May = c(7.507712, 7.880196, 7.474539, 7.711562, 7.122297, 6.904684, 7.617312, 8.436277, 7.300628, 7.469907, 5.351538, 5.522463, 8.118739),
  Jun = c(7.155556, 7.267345, 8.082705, 6.552630, 6.105434, 7.130457, 6.481846, 7.367343, 6.203369, 7.088462, 4.881926, 4.714001, 6.755348),
  Jul = c(7.553177, 7.282860, 7.608614, 6.677641, 7.297347, 6.809597, 7.401806, 7.442650, 6.141153, 6.884004, 4.901695, 5.349021, 6.622962),
  Aug = c(7.386405, 6.634843, 6.831688, 6.620460, 6.730343, 6.515561, 6.629869, 6.228851, 6.351408, 6.473058, 5.624823, 6.151726, 7.066329),
  Sep = c(6.989513, 7.744634, 6.679978, 6.488205, 6.691177, 6.463346, 6.524750, 6.080630, 5.815100, 6.493823, 5.865662, 6.225765, 6.345742),
  Oct = c(8.583059, 7.933706, 7.188722, 7.922748, 7.014266, 7.942714, 7.213666, 7.086810, 6.034656, 7.306795, 5.763610, 7.475580, 6.685429),
  Nov = c(7.414235, 7.370885, 7.389827, 6.939339, 6.688794, 6.866514, 7.564838, 7.305519, 6.369718, 6.137456, 5.682223, 7.664962, 6.868851),
  Dec = c(9.846751, 9.502180, 9.791360, 8.241256, 8.753308, 8.061643, 11.675325, 10.032838, 7.465993, 8.229741, 5.661139, 8.448881, 10.819879)
) %>% 
  pivot_longer(names_to = "Month", values_to = "Value", -Year) %>% 
  mutate(Month = factor(Month, levels = month.abb),
         tm = ym(paste0(Year, Month)))


dtrain <- d %>% 
  filter(Year<2020) 


fit <- brm(bf(
  Value ~ Month, 
  sigma ~ Month
), data=dtrain, backend='cmdstan')  


d %>% 
  add_predicted_draws(fit) %>% 
  mean_qi %>% 
  ggplot(aes(tm, .prediction, ymin = .lower, ymax = .upper)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_ribbon(alpha=0.5)
  theme(aspect.ratio = 0.61)
```

[image]

You can plainly see the prediction interval is narrower in the summer months now.  We can plot the predicted residual variance to further demonstrate this.  Below, you can see the residual standard deviation in the summer is nearly one quarter of that in the winter months

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this looks great! How do I add in the Year term again? It isn’t so noticeable in the data I used here, but it is essential.

Comment: @bgp2000 just add the year where necessary in each formula

Comment: Right, I’m only asking because adding “ + Year” gave me a gazillion stan warnings, so I thought you might have left it out for a reason, but I got it working with a different version.